# Is there any possibility to get all HTML content elements that contains "plain" text values from HTML document using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any possibility to get all HTML content elements that contains "plain" text values from HTML document using javascript?

For example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            Text1
            <p>
                Text2
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to get Text1 and Text2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can simply iterate over the DOM nodes:

```
function getTextNodes(node) {
    var result = [];
    for(var child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if(child.nodeType === 3) { // text node
            result.push(child);
        }
        else if(child.nodeType === 1) { // element node
            result = result.concat(getTextNodes(child));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var textNodes = getTextNodes(document.body);
```

This is a recursive approach, you can also select all element nodes first and then get their child text nodes.

You probably also want to filter out text nodes only containing whitespaces.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HmRA7/)